# iphone development : gesture recognition scrolling enabled simultaneously

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, scrollview, gesture-recognition

In my app I need have a swipe gesture recogniser on my background scroller for the up direction. Here is my code below

It is in viewDidLoad

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *Swipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(SwipeRecognizer:)];
Swipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp;
[backgroundScroller addGestureRecognizer:Swipe];
```

and it is the SwipeRecognizer:

```
- (void) SwipeRecognizer:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    if (sender.direction | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp){
        NSLog(@" *** SWIPE UP ***");
    }
}
```

The problem is I cant enable scrolling and capture the gesture simultaneously. when I said scrolling is not enabled, I can recognise the gesture. But I need to to scrolling and gesture recognition simultaneously. isn't it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the `gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:` method to don't block the UIScrollViews Pan recognizer

And it will work…

Dont forget to add delegate to self for gesture recogniser. As mentioned in @death7eater's comment.

Comment: thanks for the answer however it did not work. still when I set scrolling is enabled, I cannot recognize the gesture

Comment: well I used it and added `Swipe.delegate = self;` and it worked. Thanks:)

Comment: Sure this is necessary otherwise the method will not be called ;)

Comment: @lukaswelte - Had this issue from few days, resolve from your answer. FYI I just extended your answer to make it complete with the help of death7eater's comment. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem like that:

This is for the viewDidLoad:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *Swipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(SwipeRecognizer:)];
    Swipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp;
    [backgroundScroller addGestureRecognizer:Swipe];
    Swipe.delegate = self;
```

This is the SwipeRecognizer method:

```
- (void) SwipeRecognizer:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    if (sender.direction | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp){
        NSLog(@" *** SWIPE UP ***");
    }
}
```

And thanks to @lukaswelte this allows to perform multiple gestures simultaneously:

```
- (BOOL) gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    return YES;
}
```